# Use "json_field@>" for greater than, is in etc (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a table in a PostgreSQL database like

```py
id | json_field
---+-----------
1    {"name":"foo","age":20}
2    {"name":"bar", "age":10, "alive":1}
.
.
```

I can get the data for `json_field` where `name=="foo"` by doing

```sql
SELECT * from my_table where json_field@>"{'name':'foo'}"
```

or

```sql
SELECT * from my_table where (json_field->>'name')='foo'"
```

Since the first query is way faster (it is indexed as far as I understand, where the second have to loop through each record and check) is there a way to do other conditons like "greater than", "is in", "is not" e.g (some pseudo-code)

```sql
SELECT * from my_table where json_field@>"{'name':is not 'foo'}"
SELECT * from my_table where json_field@>"{'name':>'foo'}"
SELECT * from my_table where json_field@>"{'age':is in '(20,50)'}"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Postgres 12 or later, you can use a [JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) query:

```
SELECT * 
from my_table 
where json_field @@ '$.name <> "foo"';

SELECT * 
from my_table 
where json_field @@ '$.age == 20 || $.age == 50'
```

If you are using an older Postgres version, you will need to extract the values and use "normal" SQL expressions:

```
SELECT * 
from my_table 
where json_field ->> 'name' <> 'foo';


SELECT * 
from my_table 
where (json_field ->> 'age')::int in (20,50);
```

To make that efficient you will have to create indexes for those expressions:

```
create index on my_table ( (json_field ->> 'name') );
create index on my_table ( ((json_field ->> 'age')::int) );
```

That's the price you have to pay for de-normalizing your data model.

Comment: I should maybe have included the version, but I think it aint 12 since I get the error `SQL Error [1] [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb @@ unknown;`

Comment: Also, these JSONPATH expressions will not be able to use an index, right? I'd say you should avoid JSO with this requirement.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: in theory the `@@` operator _can_ make use of an index, but that's typically much less efficient then with a properly normalized model

Comment: @CutePoison: then you are using a Postgres version older than 12

Comment: It's version 10.17